# Where can I turn off paperclips validation with save(false) command

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

I have a blog application for Rails 5. It has a file attachment, which is not correctly validated by paperclip 5.1.0 gem. So I want to turn validation off in paperclips save method. How to do that?

I have articles_controller with:

```
def create
  @article = Article.new(article_params)

  if @article.save
    redirect_to @article
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end

...

private
  def article_params
    params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text, :attachment)
  end
end
```

Where do I change paperclips save method to save(false) in order to turn off validation of attachments.

The command `do_not_validate_attachment_file_type :attachment` does not work properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From the comment on git issue:](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/2195#issuecomment-217446987)

> i've just discovered that for `do_not_validate_attachment_file_type` to stop the validation you have to add an initializer in `config/initializer/paperclip.rb`
>   with
>   `Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:validate_media_type] = false`
>   I couln't find this in the docs only in the NEWS file

Comment: Upload works now, but Now it does not find my attachments anymore when i want to download them :-(

Comment: Up and download are OK after I have deleted and reloaded production DB entries. Thanks a lot!